# apache virtualhost (windows) not changing DocumentRoot

Tags: apache, virtualhost, vhosts

When setting up a vHost on apache (windows 10), everything works fine - instead of the DocumentRoot.
It's still the htdocs-directory instead of the one I set in httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin your@email.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\Test"
    ServerName www.test.test
    <Directory "C:\Test">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I also added the domain to the hosts folder at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc> to. So that part works fine:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
    127.0.0.1       www.test.test
```

Just when changing the documentRoot in the httpd.conf file like:

```
#DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
DocumentRoot "C:\Test"
<Directory "C:\Test">
...
```

it seems to work. But that can't be a proper solution...

Comment: Looks good to me. In theory paths should use forward slashes but in practice backslashes work fine. Are you using Apache/2.4, actually loading `httpd-vhosts.conf` and restarting the service after making changes?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález What do you mean by "actually loading httpf-vhosts.conf"?

And ofc I restarted everything after. Even the computer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache doesn't load automatically every file it founds under the `conf` directory. You need to use the [Include](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#include) directive to load explicitly those you need, as in:

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

It's also possible to load complete directories, e.g.:

```
Include "C:/Data/vhosts/*.conf"
```

You can verify what files are being loaded with this command:

```
httpd -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES
```

... and what virtual hosts are being defined with:

```
httpd -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
```

Comment: Thanks! In what file do I have to use these commands? In the vhost?

Comment: From a [command prompt](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/open-cmd) or PowerShell.